# Does CakePHP have a native MERGE method for datasources?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I need to save model data via a T-SQL [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), the [Saving your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) documentation doesn't mention any MERGE functionality.

Can I construct a MERGE query using Cake PHP in a "safe" way (in a way that uses their SQL injection protection) or will I have to use a Stored Procedure for this?

I'm using CakePHP 2.0 and SQL Server 2005 database.

Comment: I've just found out MERGE doesn't exist except in SQL Server 2005 and below. We will eventually be upgrading so I'd be interested to see if there is any native way to do this with Cake's API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cake doesn't seem to support that syntax unfortunately. I guess, in theory you would pass it as an option in the `conditions` array, like you do with a list of [`OR` or `AND` clauses](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions), but Cake doesn't pick up on that.

So I'm afraid you're bound to use [the `query()`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1027/query) syntax in combination with [the Sanitize library](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1183/Data-Sanitization).

Comment: That's what it's looking like. Thanks.